# Summarizing category values within a nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of elements in R structured like this:

```
[[1]]
     value      weight
[1,]     1 0.085308057
[2,]     1 0.251184834
[3,]     1 0.009478673
[4,]     1 0.180094787
[5,]     1 0.445497630
[6,]     1 0.028436019

[[2]]
     value    weight
[1,]     1 0.1753555
[2,]     2 0.1706161
[3,]     1 0.3317536
[4,]     3 0.3222749
```

I am trying to add the weights for each "value" category within each level of the list which would result in something like the following:

```
Unit  value   weight
1     1       1.0000000
2     1       0.5071091
2     2       0.1706161
2     3       0.3222749
```

There are approximately 2000 "units" that I need to summarize, so it would not be feasible to extract values from each one separately without a loop function, but I am having trouble writing the code to perform this task.

I also understand that I could turn the list into a dataframe in order to perform these calculations, but because each element of the list has different numbers of rows, I am unsure of how to go about doing this.

I am still new to learning R, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a `dput` of that first two elements of the list you showed? Are the elements within the list are `data.frame`s or matrices?

Answer (score 2):

So this is very easy to solve using `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package v>=1.9.5 (see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for installation instructions)

I'm not sure if your list contain `data.frame`s or matrices. If the later is the case, first do (we will call your list `l`)

```
l <- lapply(l, as.data.frame)
```

Then, the solution is straight forward

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(l, idcol = "Unit")[, .(weight = sum(weight)), by = .(Unit, value)]
#    Unit value    weight
# 1:    1     1 1.0000000
# 2:    2     1 0.5071091
# 3:    2     2 0.1706161
# 4:    2     3 0.3222749
```

---

Alternatively, same result could be achieved using a combination of `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unnest(l, "Unit") %>%
  group_by(Unit, value) %>%
  summarise(weight = sum(weight))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: Unit
# 
#   Unit value    weight
# 1   X1     1 1.0000000
# 2   X2     1 0.5071091
# 3   X2     2 0.1706161
# 4   X2     3 0.3222749
```

Comment: I've determined that the elements of the list are in fact dataframes. I tried to use the rbindlist code that you suggested, but keep getting the error "Error in rbindlist(l, idcol = "Unit") : unused argument (idcol = "Unit")"

Comment: You didn't install it from GitHub. I specifically told you to. Again, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Please install v 1.9.5

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was having trouble installing the GitHub version, but eventually got it to work. I also tried the tidyr/dplyr solution which also worked.

Comment: NP. Glad I could help.